# Filesystem unmounted after machine reboot

Tags: filesystems, aix

I'm having some problems last weekend according to various filesystems are unmounted on monday morning, having them mounted and running the work days before. During the weekend the machine reboot but i think the filesystem should be mounted even after a machine reboot.

Any idea of why the filesystem get unmounted after a reboot ?
Where can i look (system file) to change this behaviour and be sure it will be mounted after a reboot ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check under /etc/filesystems and add your filesystem there, then run the mount YOUR_FILESYSTEM to check if it work.

Let see you want joe1 to be mounted each time, you'll have to edit /etc/filesystems and add:

```
 /home/joe/1:
          dev        = /home/joe/1
          nodename   = vance
          vfs        = nfs
```

Then mount: mount /home/joe/1

If it work (df -g /home/joe/1 or mount) it will too on reboot.

Check the Doc to see what to put there, depending of your filesystem if it is nfs or local.

[Reference IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.files/filesystems.htm?lang=en)